# Validations for Importing CSV data into MySql database in Rails 3.1?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, validation, csv, ruby-on-rails-3.1

i implemented the task of  importing data from csv into MySQL database successfully. Now, my requirement is: i need to get error message with line number, if there is any mis match of data in csv file while importing.

This is my controller code:
**`require 'csv'`  #at the top and followed by...

```
def load_csv
# no code
end

def import_csv
parsed_file = CSV.foreach(params[:csv].tempfile,:headers => true) do |row|
row = row.to_hash.with_indifferent_access
Institute.create!(row.to_hash.symbolize_keys)
redirect_to :action => :index
end
```

In my view/ load_csv.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(:institute, :url => import_csv_institutes_path,  :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
<div class="field">
<%= file_field_tag :csv %>
<%= f.submit 'Import' %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

These are the only two steps i used for importing. Model validations are working only for form and for csv, an error page displayed..
Please try to help me out.........................

Answer (score 0):

Assign an error message to the flash[:notice] variable in the import_csv method. Do it before redirect.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html